Expandable TouchScreenButton Texture
How can I make a TouchScreenButton expandable in Godot so that it doesn't stretch on the edges? When using a regular Button, we can edit the theme and under `Style.normal` we can add StyleBoxTexture that behaves like a NinePatchRect to prevent stretching on the edges. How can I achieve this with a TouchScreenButton?
TouchScreenButton Texture can be expanded with out streching the edge like ninepachrect
